# How to access clustered Vert.x event bus without being a cluster member?

Tags: vert.x

I cannot find any example of a (client) JVM verticle communicating with clustered event bus while not joining the cluster as a full member (without causing cluster repartitioning onto a client.)

A use case: Admin UI application tapping into cluster’s event bus for management or monitoring purposes occasionally but not staying connected all the time.

Are there any design patterns or practices on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options,

1. You can use the TCP Eventbus Bridge, e.g. https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-tcp-eventbus-bridge/java/
2. If you are using Vertx Web in the Vert.x Cluster, you can open the SockJS support, which mostly is a websocket bridge, - https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_sockjs_event_bus_bridge

In general, you have to open one bridge in cluster, and make your client connect to that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I’m already started thinking in that direction but what is puzzling me from Vert.x documentation about [TCP bridge](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-tcp-eventbus-bridge/java/) is […] _the protocol is simple enough to efficiently provide an integration interface with non-JVM applications._ but I am using JVM applications on both sides which leads me to a conclusion there must be a better way bridge even bus. Do I miss some more native bridge than SocksJS or plain TCP bridge?

Comment: It does not care which type of you application, _JVM_ or _non-JVM_. As long as it's not a Vert.X application, you have to use the **bridge**. On the other side, if your application is in Vert.X, and running in the cluster mode. You should config your cluster provider's config, e.g. [config the cluster manager](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-hazelcast/java/#_configuring_this_cluster_manager). In cluster mode, all you need is about send/receive messages via [EventBus](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#event_bus)